# How to export Voronoi cell into mask?

Tags: python, voronoi

I am using scipy.spatial to calculate the voronoi cell in my image and to stack the result on my image by using:

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread('img.tif', 0)
pks = np.loadtxt('pks.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows = 1)
vor = Voronoi(pks)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
ax = plt.gca()
voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=False, line_colors='y',
                line_width=2, line_alpha=0.6, point_size=2, ax=ax)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

How to extract each cell into masks as shown below?

[image: extract mask]